# How to set file name and window name while opening file with JhiDataUtils.openFile()

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am working on the Jhipster Stack. I see that I can open a file using `JhiDataUtils.openFile()` by passing the content and the file content type.

Also, the file opens in a new tab. However, the browser title remains `Untitled`. Is there an improvement in the API to set the browser title?

Thanks,
Dharmendra

Comment: Which frontend framework?

Comment: Angular 6 + Bootstrap

Comment: No but it would be a useful improvement to contribute to ng-jhipster, it would probably mean adding title as a parameter of openFile() and a line `win.document.title = title;` to https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/62700aa6c8f21824b40e6d878c07a21c8b8369db/src/service/data-util.service.ts#L65-L71

Comment: exactly. It can be easily done too. can we somehow override it or that will take extending the JhiDataUtils?

Comment: Overidding it could be more complex as there are 2 conditional branches in openFile: one for IE (Edge?) and one for other browsers. So adding the feature to ng-jhipster is probably the simplest and cleanest way to do it.

Comment: do u think I can pull and submit the changes. I have never done open source before :)

Comment: Absolutely, you will have to submit 2 pull requests: one for ng-jhipster (very easy, see README), one for generator-jhipster (a bit more complex but there's a guide) see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md Feel free to contact me directly on gitter for more guidance